# Google Wallet Sandbox - No data sent to postback URL

Tags: android-pay

I am trying to setup a Google sandbox payment system and all is fine up until Google tries to send data to my system and then comes back with the following warning message:

```
Unfortunately, we could not confirm your purchase with the merchant's server. Your order has been canceled. Please contact the merchant if this problem continues.
```

I see that Google tried to contact my server:

```
[22/Sep/2014:14:05:18 -0400] "POST /walletresponse/purchase HTTP/1.1" 301 657 "-" "Google-In-App-Payments; (+http://www.google.com/payments)" 20255
```

Looking in the chrome->console->network->preview I see the JWT token which works if manually sent to the site. Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to debug *server-side* and check if you are [responding correctly to the postback (within 10 seconds)](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/postback). If you send it manually, what is the `response` of/from your server?

> *Important: If you specify a postback URL, your server must respond promptly and correctly to the HTTP POST messages that Google sends for each transaction. Otherwise, the transaction will be canceled.*
>
> > Responding to the postback
> >
> > Your server must send a 200 OK response for each HTTP POST message that Google sends to your postback URL. To send this response, your server must:
> >
> > 1. Decode the JWT that's specified in the jwt parameter of the POST message.
> > 2. Check to make sure that the order is OK.
> > 3. Get the value of the JWT's "orderId" field.
> > 4. Send a 200 OK response that has only one thing in the body: the "orderId" value you got in step 3.

Hth...

Comment: The server responds instantly with the orderId that is contained within the JWT

Comment: Further it now says: Sorry, we were unable to process this request. Please try again later. Is Google just having issues with their sandbox in general?

Comment: @user2694306 Yup, can confirm/reproduce that sandbox issue right now: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)`  on POST to `https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/api/v1/purchase_options`

Comment: @user2694306 - just fyi, sandbox seems to be fine now (re: the `503` issue seems resolved).

Answer (score 0):

Googles servers came back online and now it seems to be working